# Passing parameter as a string containg white spaces in javascript's onclick function

Tags: javascript, html

```
"<button onclick=editRecords('" + partId + "')>Add Quantity</button>";
```

If I pass the `partId` string without spaces, it's working fine. But if I pass `'MRF 01'`, it gives me

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL.

Why is this and how can I fix that?

Comment: Shouldn’t this be `"<button … onclick='editRecords(\'" + partId + "\')'> …"`?

Comment: It gives Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: Why? You could post some more of your code. I don’t know what else is interfering.

Comment: If i undo your code its working for string without spaces.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;` whenever you pass space as a function parameter. If you are using js to generate onclick, use encodeURIComponent.

```
"<button onclick=editRecords('" + encodeURIComponent(partId) + "')>Add Quantity</button>";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Its working. But if i have to pass multiple paramaters then what should i do?

Comment: editRecords("mh&nbsp;01","secondParameter");  //same technique..use comma to seperate parameters, use &nbsp whenever you need a space..also remember that your editRecords function must exactly have 2 arguments.Example editRecords(i,j)

Comment: onclick=editRecords(' " + encodeURIComponent(partId) + " ,  " + encodeURIComponent(partName) +"  ')
Is above working fine for two params?

Comment: yes...it looks correct..you have encoded both parameters. Vote up if you are satisfied with my answer :) thanks Gurpinder ji :)

Comment: Should i decode the partId in editRecords function ?

Comment: yes use decodeURIComponent("YourString");  function :)

Answer (score 6):

> **From the poster himself.** It's a primarily opinion based answer, there is nothing conventional in using single quotes (I have discovered C syntax and now I prefer double quotes...).

I would rather change the organisation of quotes in order to get a cleaner code. This will makes it more readable as well as more conventional (in my point of view):

```js
var msg = 'Sometimes SO looks like a McDonalds drive through.';
var html = '<button onclick="clickHandler(\'' + msg + '\')">click me</button>';
function clickHandler (msg) { alert(msg); }
document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

Even more conventional would be to follow [Felix Kling's wisdom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30961261/1636522) (last line).

Answer (score 3):

If an HTML attribute value is supposed to contain a space, then you have to use quotation marks to delimit the value.

Pay attention to the syntax highlight here:

```
<span foo=bar baz ></span>
```

This is an attribute `foo` with value `"bar"` and a boolean attribute `baz`.

On the other hand, this

```
<span foo="bar baz"></span>
```

is an attribute `foo` with value `"bar baz"`. Notice how `baz` is highlighted differently?

To fix your issue, either put quotation marks around the value of `onclick`, or better, [use a different way to bind the event handler](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that this is the best option. You can set any attribute you want.

```
var e = document.createElement("span");
e.className = "close-li";
e.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
e.setAttribute('data-toggle', 'modal');
e.setAttribute('data-target', '#CreateModal');
e.setAttribute("onClick", "FunctionName(" + parameters + ");" );
e.innerText = "×";
$('#id').append(e);  //Id would be the place where you want to append. I used jquery so, I used append
```

Answer (score 0):

String parameters with white space

```
<input type="button" onClick="return myFunction('10', 'your text hear')" />
```

**or**
PHP string variables with white space

```
<input type="button" onClick="return myFunction('<?php echo $id ?>', '<?php echo $designation ?>')" />
```

> JS Function

```
function setVisibility(id, designation) {...your js code hear...}
```